# Update programmatically xml with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-2.0

i try to update xml without linq (i am using VC 2.0). My xml file format:

```
<schedule>
<id>0</id>
<name>yusuf</name>
<status>0</status>
</schedule>

AFTER UPDATE:

<schedule>
<id>0</id>
<name>yusuf</name>
<status>1</status>
</schedule>
```

but i do not have any idea update status =0 to status =1

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) in any version of .NET (except Silverlight, where only `XDocument` exists):

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml); // or doc.Load(path)
    doc.SelectSingleNode("/schedule/status").InnerText = "1";
    string newXml = doc.OuterXml; // or doc.Save(path);
```

Comment: Just remember to check that SelectSingleNode() actually returns a node (check for null) or you will get an exception.

Comment: Well, if we are expecting it to be there, an exception is reasonable -but yes, we could throw something more obvious "status node not found" or something.

Comment: I am now waiting for the regular expression crowd to arrive to tell us how to do it properly :)

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml); // or doc.Load(path)

Path error give me. Error Detail:

"C:\\codes\\Schedule\\Schedule\\ScheduleTest\\ScheduleTest\\bin\\Debug/XmlFile/Schedules.xml"

Comment: Then please verify that your xml file is valid. It sounds like it isn't.

Comment: Note you should be using the doc.Load(path) variant for a file

Answer (score 2):

Stuff your XML into XmlDocument, do the update and then save the result.